# кодировка в ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Помогите с аяксом проблема латиницу и цифры выводит нормально, но русские не выводит раньше таких проблем не было везде ставлю utf-8, помогите заранее спасибо

```js
$(window).load(function() { //говорим скрипту что он сработает когда вся страница загрузится 
var ID = [];//оббозначаем переменную для массива 
$('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function() {//ловим клик 
ID.push($(this).data('id'));//записываем результат кликов в массив 
console.log(ID); 
});//что выдадет консоль точнее масив 
$('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function(e) { //ловим клик 
$("#basket").show("slow"); // показываем как откроется форма 
}); 
// показываем как откроется форма 
$('.compare_basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик 
$(".compare_basket").hide("slow"); 
});// показываем как откроется форма 
$('#basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик 
$(".compare_basket").show("slow"); 

console.log(ID); //что выдадет консоль 
$.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос 
url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
data: {id: ID}, // даные которые передатся 
type: "POST", // метод 
beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
},
success: function(response){ 
$(".col-md-12.ajaxDivId_1").html(response); 
}, // если запрос удачный выводим то что вернул скрипт php 
error: function(er){ alert(er); }, // если запрос не удался выводим ошибку 
}) 
.done(function(data) { //отладочный запрос по которому заносятся данные 
// выводим отладочную информацию 

}); 


}); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй указать 'contentType' в вызове AJAX-метода. Например, так:

```
var ajax_url = < твой адрес >;

$.ajax({
    data: parameters,
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_url,
    timeout: 20000,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-5",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: callback
});
```

Также укажи кодировку на сервере. Например, для PHP:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-5'); ?>
```

Кроме того, я рекомендую использовать .escape() метод JavaScript. Ты можешь использовать его совместно с jQuery, передавая значение формы так:

```
var encodedString = escape($("#formFieldID").val());
```

В JavaScript я могу выделить 3 метода для решения проблем с кодировкой:

1) .escape();

2) .encodeURI();

3) .encodeURIComponent().

Подробнее о каждом из них советую прочесть в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/17640/).